# Mean of two normal variates

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal variates find the mean value of the greater of $|X|$ and $|Y|$

Comment: Are you asking $\text{E}[|X||Y|]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\max(|X|,|Y|)=\frac{1}{2}(|X+Y|+ |X-Y|)$. Now use the linearity of expectation. Note that each of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ has normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2$.

Now we need to find the mean of $|W|$, where $W$ is normal mean $0$, variance $\sigma^2$. By symmetry this is the mean of $W$ given that $W\ge 0$.